# Is this true about the inverse sine?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

It is known that $ \sin(-x)=-\sin x \ $.
Bbut when we say:

$$ \arcsin(-x)=-\arcsin x$$

Is this true? Is it the same with the other trigonometric functions "inverse"?

Comment: It _is_ an odd function _on its domain_.  This is also true for inverse tangent.  Note that,  inverse cosine is _not_ an even function about the $ \ y-$ axis, since the range is chosen as $ \ [ 0 \ , \ \pi ] \ $ .

Comment: Let $f$ be bijective odd function and take $y\in \text{im}(f)$.

To prove that $f^{-1}$ is odd note the following:
$$\begin{align} 
-y=-y&\implies -y=-f\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)\\
&\implies f\left(f^{-1}(-y)\right)=f\left(-f^{-1}(y)\right)\\
&\implies f^{-1}\left(f\left(f^{-1}(-y)\right)\right)=f^{-1}\left(f\left(-f^{-1}(y)\right)\right)\\
&\implies f^{-1}(y)=-f^{-1}(y).
\end{align}$$

It follows by modus ponens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of any odd function (if it exists) is also an odd function.

If $f(x)$ is odd and $y = f(x)$ it must be that $-y = f(-x)$.

Using the inverse function we can say that $x = f^{-1}(y)$ and that $-x = -f^{-1}(y)$. Now take the inverse of the second equation and find that $f^{-1}(-y) = f^{-1}(f(-x)) = -x$.

We have now shown that $f^{-1}(y) = x$ and $f^{-1}(-y) = -x$ so the inverse must be an odd function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta=\arcsin{(-x)}$.  Then
$$\sin\theta=-x$$
$$-\sin\theta=x$$
$$\sin(-\theta)=x$$
$$-\theta=\arcsin{x}$$
$$\theta=-\arcsin{x}$$
Therefore, $-\arcsin{x}=\arcsin{(-x)}$.